# fseek fails on open file pointer

Tags: c, file, fseek, libmagic

I'm having trouble with fseek. I have a file pointer that contains fetched HTTP data. I then let libmagic determine the mime type of the file and want to rewind afterwards:

```
char *mime_type (int fd)
{
    char *mime;
    magic_t magic;

    magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
    magic_load(magic, MAGIC_FILE_NAME);
    mime = (char*)magic_descriptor(magic, fd);

    magic_close(magic);
    return (mime);
}

int fetch_pull() {
    fetch_state = fopen("/tmp/curl_0", "r");
    if (fetch_state == NULL) {
      perror("fetch_pull(): Could not open file handle");
      return (1);
    }
    fd = fileno(fetch_state);
    mime = mime_type(fd);
    if (fseek(fetch_state, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
      perror("fetch_pull(): Could not rewind file handle");
      return (1);
    }
    if (mime != NULL && strstr(mime, "text/") != NULL) {
      /* do things */
    } else if (mime != NULL && strstr(mime, "image/") != NULL) {
      /* do other things */
    }
    return (0);
}
```

This throws "fetch_pull(): Could not rewind file handle: Bad file descriptor". What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/tmp/curl_0` is a pipe, isn't it? You cannot rewind a pipe. What's read is gone.

And you cannot combine FILE operations and file descriptor operations, since FILEs have an additional buffer, they read ahead.

If `/tmp/curl_0` is a [regular file](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Unix_file_types&oldid=600026196#Regular_file), then open a file descriptor with [`open(const char *path, int oflag, ...)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html). After invoking `mime_type(fd)`, you can first rewind the stream, then wrap the file descriptor into FILE handle with [`fdopen(int fildes, const char *mode)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html). Or just close the file descriptor and use the regular `fopen()` afterwards:

```
int fd = open("/tmp/curl_0", O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("Could not open file");
    return -1;
}
char *mime = mime_type(fd);

    /***** EITHER: */

close(fd);
FILE *file = fopen("/tmp/curl_0", "r");

    /***** OR (the worse option!) */

if (lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
    perror("Could not seek");
    return -1;
}
FILE *fdopen = fopen(fd, "r");

    /***********/

if (!file) {
    perror("Could not open file");
    return -1;
}
/* do things */
fclose(file);
```

Comment: /tmp/curl_0 is a file. It seems like I misunderstood file descriptors. I thought that file descriptors are just the OS's integer representation of a file stream. Am I wrong?

Comment: File descriptors are a handle for a file stream. FILE objects add a buffer and abstraction for all sorts of streams. You can use `fdopen()` to wrap a descriptor, but you should never find a need to use `fileno()`.

Comment: Why is the second way worse than the first?

Comment: Because it is a needless micro optimization. Far more difficult to understand (→ maintainability), and at best it is some nanoseconds faster, because the OS caches the file metadata quite efficiently as is.